# How to get photo place from getPlaceDetails? in VUE

Tags: vue.js, google-places-api, photo

So I have a search box, and after I click "enter", I want to display the photo of the place I've just chose.
I don't really know how to do that, and after some searches on the internet, I've found out of getPlaceDetails API.
This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test-jest</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

My App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/search">Search</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

And finally, the superstar, my Search component:

```
<template>
  <div id="search-wrapper">
    <div>
    <input id="search-input" ref="vue_google_autocomplete"
        placeholder="Search"
        class="search-location"
        onfocus="value = ''"
        type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (this.$refs.vue_google_autocomplete),
      {types: ['geocode'],componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}}
    );
      this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      let ac = place.address_components;
      let lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      let lon = place.geometry.location.lng();
      var city = ac[0]["short_name"];
      var country = ac[3]["long_name"];

      console.log(`You're going to ${city}, which is in ${country}`);
      console.log(ac);
    });
  }
  }
</script>
```

Can someone please help me to to display the photo of the place I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Places are defined within this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest. Most roads etc. do not return images.

Source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

Check if your response has an `photos[]` array, the photo's should be there if it matches the above defined places.

Comment: It didn't have a photos array.
Today, after some hard research I've finally understood how it works.